# Ubuntu 13.10 or 13.04 or 12.04?

Tags: lts

I have used ubuntu 13.10 for last month. I enjoyed using it, but it was very buggy and unstable. Every now and then I experienced random freezes, mishappens and various other bugs. Because of this reason, I installed ubuntu 12.04 just now. Even though I know, that 12.04 should be more stable, I miss various new features, one of them is unity tweak tool support.
I would like to ask you about 13.04. Is it stable? Personally, I use computer for the following:

browsing the internet

writing various documents

reading

studying in general

watching films / listening to music (spotify)

programming in c++, java(android), and java in general

flashing custom android roms to my phone

I would like to experience the good side of linux: stability, performance, customizability.
I liked 13.10 because of customizability options, but stability was a dog.

Which one, if you were me, would you choose and why?
Thank you for your tips.

EDIT: also I would like to ask about 14.04. I have heard that it is much more stable then 13.10 :)

Answer (score 0):

right now 14.04 is not yet complete. There's only a "beta" version. so if you try 14.04 now I think you'd find it even more buggy.

...personally I think that 13.04 had less bugs than 13.10 but the thing is that its not supported anymore. ... and it's not as fast as 13.10 but I think it's less buggy

You can try installing **and updating** it. If it's convenient for you then use it. why not.

I really want to know what bugs are you having on 13.10; I'm using it now

Answer (score 0):

I've begun using **Ubuntu** (after several years of exploring the vast world of Linux distros) **since version 11.04**, and have upgraded to the next version (YY.MM) every time with great satisfaction until October 2013.

However, **upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10 was a great disappointment for me**, including numerous problems like a very problematic upgrading process, **Nautilus Actions Extra** package (which I consider indispensable) not working, etc. So I had to switch back to my good old **Ubuntu 13.04 (64-bit)**, which I had fortunately saved using **Clonezilla**, although 13.10 seems to run faster.

Therefore, I can say that **Ubuntu 13.04** might also be very satisfactory for you.

I now pray that upgrading from 13.04 to 14.04 will be as good as my previous experience ;-)

Comment: You will have to upgrade to 13.10 first, before being able to upgrade to 14.04. One cannot "skip" a version, unless one is coming from the previous LTS release. Besides that, 13.04 will no longer be supported in a very short while from now. That means you will no longer receive any security updates. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: @Gx1sptDTDa: Thanks for the warning. I thought it was possible to skip versions. I nevertheless have moved my **/home** folder to a separate **/home** partition. I'll perhaps try upgrading from 13.04 to 14.04, and if it's not possible, I'll try a fresh install of 14.04 making note of all the additional packages I've installed, etc.

Comment: That said, my update from 13.04 to 13.10 also did not go flawless. It stopped somewhere down the middle, leading to me to have to boot into a terminal (luckily that still worked) and do some manual installing and reconfiguring.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using ubuntu 12.04 since it came out and I recently upgraded to the beta version of 14.04. It's pretty stable and ready to use.
I love the new look and the speed. Everything has changed you will notice it right after the first use.